# the function map and reduce in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

The return value of the [`map` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in Python 3 is an *Iterator*.

Why can the [`reduce` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) use the `map` result, when it needs an *Iterable*?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from functools import reduce
def fn(x, y):
  return x * 10 + y
def char2num(s):
   digits = {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}
   return digits[s]
reduce(fn, map(char2num, '13579'))
```

Comment: You can pass the return value of `map` to `reduce` because an iterator is an iterable. Iterable just means "you can call `iter` on it". If you call `iter` on an iterator, you'll get the same iterator back again. Please include your example code *as text*, not as an image. It's much easier to view and interact with text (for instance, I can copy and past it into my own interpreter).

Comment: You may be interested in the answers to this highly voted question on the distinctions between iterators and iterables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration I personally prefer my answer to this somewhat worse and now closed question (but of course I'm biased): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323783/methods-that-take-iterators-instead-of-iterables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reduce` function can consume the iterator returned by `map` because an iterator is an iterable object. All iterators have an `__iter__` method that returns the iterator itself. That's all you need to be iterable (an `__iter__` method that returns an iterator, though you can instead get by with a `__getitem__` method in some cases).

That said, a few people will be careless of their terminology and use the term *iterable* when an *iterator* won't do (perhaps because they need to iterate on the same input several times). There's unfortunately not a single precise name for that subset of iterables (though *sequence* is often appropriate).

The Python documentation is usually pretty good about this though. If it says a function expects an iterable, and iterator should always be acceptable. If a function or method needs to iterate over the input multiple times (as for instance, `str.join` does), it will build its own temporary sequence internally if the input isn't already of an acceptable type.